# Send variables through tag property on label

Tags: c#

I have a `Label` where I added a Tag property like:

```
Label lbl = new Label
{
    ...     
    Tag = item.item1 + item.item2 + item.item3
};
```

Then I added mouse clic event like:

```
lbl.MouseClick += lbl_MouseClick;
```

Once I do that in Mouseclick event I get that tag as:

```
private void lbl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = sender as Label;
}
```

So I can access to tag using `lbl.Tag` but I get concatenated string: `item1 item2 item3`, my question is, is there any way to separate items in order to have item1 , item2 and item3 again? or there is another property where I can send variables like this? Regards

Comment: What is `item`? If that is, e.g., a class object, you could set the `Label.Tag = item;` and than cast it back on the `MouseClick` event: `Label lbl = sender as Label;` `[Type] item = ([Type])lbl .Tag;`. You can then access it's members as `item.Item1` etc.

Comment: suppose item is a string so I have string1 + string2 + string3. When I receive it on MouseClick event I receive string1stringstring3 as 1 string, how can I set them into original variables? @Jimi

Comment: `item` can't be a string. Strings don't have members (`item.Item1`). If those are actually strings, you should represent them as such and state this, in your question. The Type you're dealing with directly influence the solution someone can give you. That being said, you could insert a separator between them (e.g., `item.Item1 + "[Separator]" + item.Item2 + "[Separator]" (...)`) and then `.Spilt()` the string on `MouseClick` => `string[] result = lbl.Tag.ToString().Split(new[] { "[Separator]", [Options] });`.